# Material-UI password input required

Tags: textfield, material-ui

Using MUI @Next and the [TextField](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/) component.

MUI very nicely adds a little * at the end of the label when you add *required* as a prop, however it seems to not work out of the box when you add the *endAdornment* in order to enable a "show password" toggle.

I have created [a codesandbox of my issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/n4v84060q0).

The regular `<Texfield />` component shows the * as expected, but the also required password field doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making the codesandbox reproduction of my issue, I found the answer, but thought I'd leave it here for others who come across this.
The *required* prop has to go on the `<FormControl />` wrapper of the input:

```
<FormControl required ... >
   <InputLabel ... >Password</InputLabel>
   <Input ... />
</FormControl>
```